# Share VPN for Windows 7 Host running Ubuntu VMplayer with Cisco AnyConnect VPN

Tags: networking, vmware, vpn, nat, vmware-player

I've attempted to search the forums for any insight on whether this is possible or not with no luck. I have a Windows 7 Host Machine running an Ubuntu 10.04 Virtual Machine with VMware Player. When I am not connected to the VPN my Ubuntu VM can access the internet using NAT bridging by bridging the VMware Network Adapter 8 connector to the Wireless Adapter in the Windows Network Connections dialog. If I connect to my company's VPN on the Windows host using Cisco AnyConnect VPN without changing any other settings, the VM can access the internet but cannot reach any intranet machines.

Is it possible to share this single host VPN connection with the Ubuntu VM?
If so, how can I configure the VMware Player or bridged connections to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out this is not possible. You can't share the VPN connection between host and vm.

Comment: Why is that so? With other VPN connectors, I've always been able to share the connection. Can you elaborate on the why part, please?

Comment: Share the VPN Connection on your Windows host with your Linux VMPlayer virtual machine? I forget where I read this since the question is a little old. But you have 2 ip addresses , 1 for your VM and one for your Windows Host. No matter what combination of networking settings I put on the VM there was no shared connection possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open new Network Adapter.
For do that ; 
1. Right Click on Your Virtual Machine 
2. Under the table of "Hardware" tab click on "Add..." button
3. Choose "Network Adapter" and press "Finish" button
4. Choose your new Network Adapter.It will be add with new numb under your last 
network adapter.
5. From right side of the page , choose 'Bridged" in "Network connection" tab
6. Check "Replicate physical network connection state"
7. Click on ok
8. Run your vpn on your main OS and then run your Virtual Machine
9. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

We have a draytek router and use the Windows VPN client on the host. Its possible this may be dependent on the type of VPN and possibly how its configured IE security etc but certainly for this type of simple setup, the following works for me.

You should be able to share a VPN on the Host with the Guest by using NAT instead of Bridged mode:

The steps I use are as follows:

1. Connect to the vpn from the host and verify it's accessible
2. View the settings for the VM
3. Select 'Network Adapter' from the Hardware list
4. Under 'Network Connection' Select the option 'NAT: Used to share the host’s IP address'

Once the VM has started or applied the settings, the VPN should now be accessible from the guest.